# certificate error while login with PF https connection

Tags: pingfederate

I'm facing certificate error while login with PF template.
I have added the PF domain in my trusted sites list and reduced the security level to low but still have seen certificate error. from Fiddler, can get

"The remote server (192.0.0.1) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors".

Creating new certificate in ping federate same name with PF domain.

also seen from PF response like below.
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
max-age:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

I dont have any idea how to change this response headers.

Any idea about how to resolve both fiddler error and pf response header.

Do we really need to correct the both?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This commonly means that the server name you are requesting in your browser request does not match the Subject of the SSL Certificate that is being used by PingFederate for the Runtime or Admin console. This happens most frequently when you request your PingFederate server by IP Address and not the FQDN.

Comment: Thanks Ian. in Response headers have seen Expires and max age is set to 1970. is there any way to change this to current year or 1 year later?

Comment: This is used for Cache Control and is basically telling the HTTP client that the data is stale and to not cache it for reuse. Why do you need to change it?

Comment: user does refresh in end app, he is redirected to PF startSSO.ping for authentication. Chrome and firefox browsers communicate with PF and make authentication successful by sending cookie (seen from fiddler) information with SSO url. but IE loads login page and ask user name and password again. noticed cookie informations are not passed with startSSO URL.so thought of clearing cert error and seen 'expires and max-age' also be staled date info. believe browsers invalidate cookies if they found max-age is lower than current date.

Comment: The browser will only invalidate a cookie if the cookie has an expiration time stamp on it which is different than the Expires header we are talking about. I'd start a new question here on that topic or head over to the new Ping Identity Community discussion group (on their website) and ask the question

Comment: Thanks Ian. Shall i post a new question on this(issue with IE only).

Comment: Yes. Best practice is to have only 1 issue per post. FYI - you'll have more PF experts on the Ping Community page.